# Factorial using two functions Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone I have a homework assignment that I am supposed to do in python 3.x

I am struggling to figure out how to do this so I'm hoping you can explain to me how to about this.

## Problem

The factorial of a positive integer n (written n!) is the product 1 x 2 x 3 x ... x n. Write a program that asks the user to input a positive integer and then calculates and displays the factorial of the number. The program should include two functions: *getN* to which the input is sent, and which guarantees that the input is a positive integer. The function *fact* should calculate the factorial value. The program (main) should then display the factorial value.

So far I have a rough sketch of how I want to go about this

```
#This program will show the answer to a factorial after the user inputs a value.
def getN(n):
    try:
        n = int(input("Please enter a non-negative integer: "))
    except n < 1:
        print("You did not enter a value of 1 or greater.")

def fact(n):
    count = 1
    while n > 0:
        count *= n
        n -= 1
        if n == 0:
            break
def main(n):
    n = int(input("Please enter a non-negative integer: "))
    getN(n)

main(n)
```

I believe its supposed to look something like this. If you can give me some feedback about what I should do that what be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `0` is an acceptable input - it is non-negative and it's factorial is `1`.

Comment: SO is for seeking answers to specific problems. For this type of request [code-review] is more suited.

Comment: "I'm not done with my homework" isn't a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is neither a homework completion service nor a tutoring service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see inline comments

```
def getN():
    try:
        n = int(input("Please enter a non-negative integer: "))
        if n < 1:
            raise ValueError  # it will be thrown also if input is not a valid int
    except ValueError:  # n < 1 is not an Exception type
        print("You did not enter a value of 1 or greater.")
    else:
        return n

def fact(n):
    count = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):  # you see how simple it is with for loop?
        count *= i
    return count

def main():
    n = getN()  # before you were just asking n twice, never using fact()
    print(fact(n)) 

main()
```

Comment: there is no `return` in fact function.

Comment: also - you don't need to take `n` parameter in `main` and pass it to `getN`

Comment: almost :) `def getN(n):` -> `def getN():` and in main `n = getN(n)` -> `n = getN()`

Comment: @Brett you forgot to change `def main(n):` to `def main():`

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now thank you for the help :)

Comment: @rsm, this should be your answer )

Comment: @Marat we could coin term "pair-answering" and promote it as the real thing! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems reasonable to me. It looks like you never return or print the actual factorial calculation. Maybe your function 'fact' should "return count"? In addition, you don't need to check "if n==0" in your fact function, since if it is 0 it will end the while loop due to the condition of the while loop.